# Whate are !g and !wiki called in Firefox Browser

Tags: search, firefox

I want to know the term used to denote `!g [search term]` and `!wiki [search term]` which is used in the search area of Firefox.

Additionally, I'd like to know if it is possible to add a custom term like that, say `!myOwnShortcut [search term]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called [smart keywords](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar), though so far as I know, they're powered by bookmarks. The idea is that you can

1. right-click on any search box in a website
2. Select "Add a keyword for this search"
3. Firefox will prompt you to bookmark the site, and the prompt also provides an input for a "keyword", which you can then use in the URL bar (the "awesome" bar) to search that specific search box in that specific website directly.

(And yes, you can definitely add your own smart keywords this way)

Final note: the keyword need not begin with a bang (`!`). So far as I know, that particular convention comes from DuckDuckGo's search engine, and they call these [bangs](https://duckduckgo.com/bang).

Now, if your default search engine happens to be DuckDuckGo, and you type `!g mySearchTerm` into the Firefox URL/"awesome" bar, then you will --by virtue of having DuckDuckGo as your default search engine in Firefox-- have that string sent to DuckDuckGo, which will then evaluate it as a DuckDuckGo `bang` and present you with search results of that `bang` at that particular website (for the `!g` `bang`, you'll be directed to Google's results for that query).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was searching for! :)